# Can a TableCellEditor tell which JTable it is editing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a `TableCellEditor` that overrides `stopCellEditing` to validate the content.  I would like to interact with the table as part of this validation.  Is there a way to determine what table we are editing?  I thought it would be `getParent()`, but it seems sometimes `getParent()` is the table and other times it's null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                      boolean isSelected,
                                      int row, int column)
```

The method of `TableCellEditor` interface has the first parameter `JTable` instance. SO you can keep the table in a field and use it in the `stopCellEditing`